# int cannot be converted to String

Tags: java

Is there any one out there that can help me figure this out. I know it probably the most simple thing you could ever code in java, but i cant figure it out for the life of me. I have just start learning java and this has me stuck.
When i compile the code it get the error "int cannot be converted to String console.printf(xy);

```
import java.io.Console;
public class ExampleProgram {
  public static void main(String[]arg) {
    Console console = System.console();
    console.printf("Below is a Power Calculation");
    int x = 2;
    int y = 2;
    int xy = x * y;
    console.printf(xy);
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use toString()?

Comment: comes back with error: int cannot be dereferenced

Comment: You need to check for the console being null. It is not guaranteed to be instantiated, depending on how the user preferences are setup.

Comment: that's because you can't call a method on a primitive. I'm not sure @ManoDestra's recommendation is a sound one.

Answer (score 3):

Use the printf format specifiers as described in the [Formatter API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax):

```
Console console = System.console();
// note that console is never guaranteed to be non-null, so check it!
if (console == null) {
    // error message
    return;
}
console.printf("Below is a Power Calculation%n");  // %n for platform independent new-line
int x = 2;
int y = 2;
int xy = x * y;
console.printf("%d", xy); // %d for decimal display
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this:

1. Converting an integer to a string can be accomplished in a variety of ways.  For example:

   ```
     xy + ""
   ```

   is an idiomatic way that relies on the special semantics of the string concatenation operator.

   ```
     Integer.toString(xy)
   ```

   is probably the most efficient.

   ```
     Integer.valueOf(xy).toString()
   ```

   converts `xy` to an `Integer` and then applies the `toString()` instance method.

   But this **won't work**<sup>1</sup>

   ```
     xy.toString()
   ```

   because 1) you cannot apply a method to a primitive, and 2) Java won't autobox `xy` to an `Integer` in that context.
2. The way you are printing the string is "kind of wrong".  The `printf` method's signature is `printf(String format, Object... args)`.  When you call it the way you are doing, you are passing the number as the `format` together with a zero-length `args` parameter.

   The `printf` method will parse the `format` looking for `%` characters that denote the substitution markers.  Fortunately, a number string doesn't contain such characters, so it will be printed literally.

   But anyway, the "right" way to use printf would be:

   ```
      printf("%d", xy)
   ```

   which relies on `printf` to do the number to string conversion.

There is another potential problem.  If you run this program on a "headless" system, the `System.console()` method is liable to return `null`.  If that happens, your program will crash with an NPE.

---

<sup>1 - confirmed with a simple test-case on Java 8.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use :
 `console.printf(String.valueOf(xy));`

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
console.printf(xy+"");
```

Comment: Even if it will work, using concatenation defeats purpose of using `printf`.